# TempVar use in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So my client has 4 queries that need to be updated every time a process is run.

I am setting up a macro to ask for user input on a variable called 'FileDate'.

Here's how it looks:

```
SetTempVar
    Name = FileDate
    Expression = InputBox("Enter FileDate (yyyymmdd):")
```

Now this works fine ( from what I can tell )

Then I wanted to use a MessageBox to display the value of the tempvar, since It's in the same macro, I didn't see any problem with this.

```
MessageBox
    Message = "You entered:" & [TempVars]![FileDate] & "."
    Beep = Yes
    Type = Informative
    Title = Input
```

I've tried several variations of this syntax with no progress...

**ISSUES**

I can't get the Messagebox to actually show the value set to that variable, it only displays the Message  - Does anyone know the proper syntax to get this into the Messagebox?

Once I figure this out, I'd like to enter it into the input box once, and then insert the variable into each query that requires an update.

Currently I'm accepting user input for every query:

```
UPDATE test_PCP_Changes SET test_PCP_Changes.Datercvd = [Enter FileDate (yyyymmdd): ]
WHERE (((test_PCP_Changes.Datercvd) Is Null));
```

I'd like it to be like:

```
UPDATE test_PCP_Changes SET test_PCP_Changes.Datercvd = [TempVars!FileDate]
WHERE (((test_PCP_Changes.Datercvd) Is Null));
```

But not sure how to pass it to the query. I assume once it's in the macro, as long as I don't remove it it should be available as long as Access is open..

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Is the only way to do the RunSQL commands from inside the macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your message on the messagebox to start with an =.

[image: Access macro with expression]

Comment: Awesome, so close, yet so far...I think more importantly is can you access this variable from UPDATE queries inside the macro...I think the answer is no. I have copied and pasted most of the queries I need into the Macro with a RunSQL command...seems to work so far. Thanks! PS If you answer the variable access question I will select as answer :)

Comment: Did you try it? The TempVars have global scope so you should be able to use them in a query. Also, your SQL query above has [TempVars!FileDate], that should be [TempVars]![FileDate]. Make sure you have it the right way in your macro.

Comment: Yea I tried multiple ways, I think you just captured one of my feeble attempts. I did try and access it from a macro, but I didn't have any luck. I just posted a new question, maybe you can look and get two answers for the price of one!

Comment: I set up a test using an update query to change a date in a table based on the FileDate TempVar. Worked without issue. Is test_PCP_changes you referenced above a table?

Comment: I set up a very simple example. Feel free to download it and try. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcflqzl8sq9jqnp/Macro%20Update%20From%20TempVars.mdb