# ImportExportSpreadsheet Import tempvar in filename

Tags: sql, ms-access, filenames, export-to-excel

[image: Filename]

Is there some way I can use the TempVar from my Macro to put it at end of Filename when Exporting?

If not is there another way I can automate the filename to include the date?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certainly can. Just use the same structure I showed you in the other post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250037/macro-tempvar-use-in-query). Your filename property should look similar:

```
="I:\Users\ME\CARDOUT\ID_CARDSLABEL(" & [TempVars]![FileDate] & ")_new.xls"
```

[image]

Comment: actually this failed.

Comment: also, when I put the equal sign in front of it, it prevented me from saving and said it was an invalid argument

Comment: I added an image of a macro I set up as a test and all the steps run without error, table gets updated, and the spreadsheet gets created. Check your FileName argument and try again.

Answer (score 0):

my words since i program with Access: never use macro's
here a translation of reasons from one of the most know Access-Specialist in german part of the world, Reinhard Kraasch:

- In macros you have no error-handler
- in macros you can not use variables, no loops and other structures
- macros you can hardly document and are not well readable
- macros cannot use API's or libraries
- in macros you cannot create systemobjects like tables, queries and cannot handle transactions
- you cannot or only hardly debug macros
- as you see yourself: you cannot copy/paste them into forums

so solution for your problem is, to create a code for this export, which is a one liner:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acFormatExcel?, [Tablename], [Filename], True
```

instead of [Filename] (or as part of it) you can use your Variable

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the name of automation, I can't really get around this unless I want to learn VBA, which I don't...so one more ? I assume this is a VBA line - Do I just create a module, and play around to get this to work? Or is this something I can enter in the macro itself?

Comment: no, not in the macro, but instead of the macro you create the code - where do you fire the macro? Assume it's a button, so change the event "on click" from macro to "event procedure", then you get into VBA code-editor

Comment: I just click the macro in the object explorer. Not that advanced...lol

Comment: I mostly agree with SEM_jmc here. If you are going to be working with Access automation, learn VBA. Macros are pretty straightforward and simple for the power users, but it look like you are trying to move beyond power user status.

Comment: Soon the company I work for will be migrating away from VBA and  learning it is discouraged from the CIO...crazy I know. I just don't want to be spending half my day doing processes (like updating 4 queries with one date) when I can use a tempVar and have a macro do it for me. I definitely see what you guys are saying though these are generally SQL based, and so far have worked flawlessly, aside from some debugging issues, which you guys have so generously helped me with. Thanks again!